# How to judge if a value is stable in a period

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to monitor a status's stability in a period.

*For example*: the on/off status of a bulb.

I want to monitor the frequency of it's being turned on/off.

Let's say it's stable or unstable in a period(e.g. per 10 seconds):

1. **unstable:** If the bulb's on/off state changes times > 3 (maybe by somebody's operator or the unstable voltage, whatever).
2. **stable:** If it's not **unstable**.

Is there a good algorithm to Implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is the right way.

Observer pattern.

Implement a class which listen to the on/off status of a bulb. So whenever the bulb goes ON/OFF this class will be notified.
Maintain a queue data structure in the same class which stores these notifications for the given time(10 seconds). Perform Dequeue such that the queue always maintains the notification that are received in the last 10 seconds only.

Whenever you want the stability of the bulb, we can look into the queue and count the number of OFFs and ONs

Comment: @keai4le In addition, rather than using simple queue you can use something like cache with entry expiry time (10s in your case). so that you no need to take care that expiry manually.

Comment: @ShivangAgarwal That sounds good, could you give me some tips about the cache.

Comment: Instead of remembering all the changes in the last 10s, just remember the last 4.  At any time, the bulb is unstable if you've seen at least 4 changes and the last 4 are all in the last 10s.